# NetLogo 5 to 6 transition: for loop

Tags: netlogo

I am fairly new to NetLogo and am trying to convert a model built in NetLogo 5.3.1 to NetLogo 6.0.3. The auto-converter did not work, so I am attempting to convert tasks to anonymous procedures manually. However, I am stuck on conversion of the following section of NL-5.3.1 code:

```
let tempNewList [ ]                                           ; to store the new list
  (foreach n-values (highest-family-id + 1) [?] [             ; search through all family-ids ever created in model
      if count turtles with [family-id = ?] >= 2 [            ; if family-id belongs to 2 or more turtles... 
        set tempNewList lput ? tempNewList                    ; ...  add to list
      ]
  ])
  set families tempNewList
```

Here, the objective is to update the 'families' global variable which is a list of family-ids which at least 2 humans hold. When opened in NL-6.3.0, this code gives the error: "? is undefined", as expected.

I renamed "?" to eachFamilyID, and used the new "->" syntax for anonymous procedures. For example, I tried changing the above code to:

```
let tempNewList [ ]                                                       
  (foreach n-values (highest-family-id + 1) [ eachFamilyID ->  
    if count turtles with [family-id = eachFamilyID] >= 2 
    [set tempNewList lput eachFamilyID tempNewList ]  ]                
    ])
set families tempNewList
```

This gives the error: 'N-VALUES expected this input to be an anonymous reporter, but got an anonymous command instead'.

After a lot of reading the [transition guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html), [programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html), [dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html) and a lot of googling, I still can't work out how to do this. Any suggestions?

Operating System: MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're facing a simple syntax issue, but I also think it might be worth taking a step back and rethinking your approach to the problem. Let's start with the syntax.

If you look at your unconverted code, you will notice that the top level structure is something like this:

```
(foreach n-values (highest-family-id + 1) [?] [ ... ])
```

There are two main primitives used here, `foreach` and `n-values`, and both of them take a task parameter.

In the case of `foreach`, that task is the whole `[ if count turtles ... ]` block, which I have elided to `[ ... ]` here.

In the case of `n-values`, that task is simply the identity function, `[?]`, which just gives you back whatever is passed to it. For example, `n-values 5 [?]` will give you the list `[0 1 2 3 4]` because those are the successive values passed as `?` by `n-values` to its task argument.

The syntax has changed in NetLogo 6, but `n-values` still needs some way to generate successive values. Now look at your converted version:

```
(foreach n-values (highest-family-id + 1) [ eachFamilyID -> ... ])
```

Can you see what's missing? There is only one anonymous procedure! Your call to `n-values` tries to use the anonymous command intended for `foreach`, which explains the error message that you are getting. To fix this, you can simply add a NetLogo 6 version of the identity function to your code:

```
(foreach n-values (highest-family-id + 1) [ n -> n ] [ eachFamilyID -> ... ])
```

That should fix your immediate problem.

Now let's take that step back. What you are trying to do is to build a list with only values that correspond to a certain criteria. In your case, you want to keep only the family IDs for families that have at least two members. NetLogo has a built-in primitive that does exactly that sort of thing: [`filter`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter). Here is one way to use it that is relatively close to what you are already doing:

```
let all-ids n-values (highest-family-id + 1) [ n -> n ]
set families filter [ id ->
  count turtles with [ family-id = eachFamilyID ] >= 2
] all-ids
```

Isn't that already nicer? It can still be improved, however. First, NetLogo 6 has a [`range`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#range) primitive that you can often use instead of `n-values`:

```
let all-ids range (highest-family-id + 1)
```

That's neat. But you could also do something like this:

```
let all-ids remove-duplicates [ family-id ] of turtles
```

This is a bit slower but it is still guaranteed to give you all the family IDs in use and you avoid the possibility of an "off by one" error.

But there is an even neater approach that you could take if you are willing to use the `table` extension. It involves the [`table:counts`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/table.html#table:counts) primitive. Here is how you could use it, supposing that you have `extensions [ table ]` at the top of your code:

```
let counts table:counts [ family-id ] of turtles
set families map first filter [ p -> last p >= 2 ] table:to-list counts
```

It looks a bit cryptic, but it has the advantage of being much fast then the other approaches (and somewhat elegant once you understand it). Let me try to unpack it a little.

The first line is simple enough: it uses `table:counts` to count how many times each `family-id` is represented in all our turtles, which is exactly the information we need! This information is stored in a "table" which associates "keys" with values. In this case, each family ID is a key and the value is how many times it appears.

Once we have that, all we need to do is some filtering to keep only the keys for which the value is at least 2. The table extension has no primitive for filtering tables, but we can easily turn a table into a list, using `table:to-list`, and then filter that list.

The result of `table:to-list` is a list of lists, where each sublist has two elements, corresponding to a key-value pair from the original table. Suppose we have only two families, family 1, which has 5 members and family 2, which has only 1 members. We would get the following list: `[[1 5] [2 1]]`. Easy enough! Now if we use `filter` on this, we need to keep only the sublists where the second member of the pair (i.e., the `last` one) is `>= 2`. That's the `filter [ p -> last p >= 2 ] ...` part of the code above.

Once the list is filtered, there is one last step: we want only the first element of each of the sublists we kept. Transforming a list into something else (which is what we want to do here) is usually done with the [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) primitive, which takes a reporter, applies it to each element of the list and returns the resulting list. In this case we directly pass it the [`first`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#first) reporter, but we could also have used an anonymous reporter like `[ p -> first p ]`.

If it was my model, however, I would take a completely different approach. Numerical IDs are a pain to work with and a big source of errors in code. NetLogo has better ways to represent relationship between things. I would create two different turtle breeds: `persons` and `families` and create links between persons and the family they belong to. Getting the families with at least two members would then just be:

```
families with [ count my-links >= 2 ]
```

Much clearer, no?

Comment: Thank you so much for your incredibly helpful answer! It is very much appreciated. I now understand that both primitives needed an anonymous procedure, and I was only providing one. Your fix worked perfectly. Thank you also for suggesting alternative ways to accomplish this. I agree these are neater, and I think using links would work well in the model. Once I have finished converting the model I will definitely go back and consider this.